# What partition type do I choose when I create partitions for Ubuntu and WIndows 7

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop with no OS. Afterwards I'll hopefully be able to install windows 7 on what's left of the hard drive.

I'm at the step where i create the partitions and not sure what to do.

I see

```
 device      type      Mount Point    format         size 

/dev/sda
  /dev/sda1  ext4                     (check)        500gb
  /dev/sda2  ext4                     (check)        250gb

 (both were selected as primary drives)
```

Do I choose anything for 'mount Point'

and

Is the Type I selected (`ext4`) going to be ok for installing both operating systems on the same hard drive on two separate partitions?

---

ALso, I have to choose between:

```
Device for boot loader installation:
- /dev/sda 750gb hard drive    or,
- /dev/sbd
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the settings you need:

You want the one for Ubuntu(the first, I presume) to be:

```
Use as: ext4 partition
Format: (check)
Mount point `/`
```

and the one to be used for Windows as blank space.  When you  install Windows, you can create a  new partiton in that free space and `format it as NTFS` or use the `NTFS(quick)` option of the Windows installer.

However, it is better to install Windows first, as it will overwrite the bootloader(GRUB) of Ubuntu. Even if you choose to install Ubuntu first, you can still recover GRUB, as per [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

I recommend either [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/54298) or the accepted one, but the accepted one is a bit harder to carry out.

Comment: THank you!! I'll probably go with the easier of the two...unless you recommend the accepted answer. I think i'm capable of doing that one too.

Comment: I'd go with the easier one, and if it doesn't work, then the accepted answer. Does my answer about the settings help?